# react hook form + material ui: Date Picker not getting the initial date

Tags: react-hook-form

I and using React hook form. I have the following date picker Controller.

```
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <Controller
              name="dateOfBirth"
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { ref, ...rest } }) => (
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                  ref={ref}
                  margin="dense"
                  fullWidth
                  id="date-picker-dialog"
                  label="Date picker dialog"
                  format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                  KeyboardButtonProps={{
                    "aria-label": "change date",
                  }}
                  {...rest}
                />
              )}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Now when I submit without changing the date it does not show `dateOfBirth` at all in the submit data.

BUt when I change the date then `dateOfBirth` is shown in the submit data

Comment: Can you share the whole form please? Or a codesanbox thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're not setting a `defaultValue`. When using `<Controller />` it is required to provide a `defaultValue`, from the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller):

> You need to either provide `defaultValue` at the field-level or `useForm` with `defaultValues`.

One other minor thing: you should pass the `ref` to the `inputRef` of your `<KeyboardDatePicker />` so RHF can link it to the actual input element.

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]