# how to use react-hook-form "register' with mui DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, yup

Im using **{...register("fieldname")}** with Textfields and Select fields in react hook form(Yup resolver),and it is working properly.But when I use it on DatePicker it is showing  [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCCQC.png) 
How can I use **{...register("fieldname")}** with DatePicker(MUI)?

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
     variant="dialog"
     format="DD/MM/yyyy"
     value={selectedDate}
     onChange={(event)=> handleDateChange(event._d)} 
     id="date"
     name='date'
     error={Boolean(errors.date)}
     helperText={errors.date?.message}
     {...register("date")} />
```

Comment: Can u add a working snippet of the error in CodeSandbox?

Comment: You have to RHF's `<Controller />` component for registering your `<KeyboardDatePicker />`. Check the Sandbox of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962464/2015452), it shows a running example of a `<KeyboardDatePicker />` used with RHF.

Comment: I now wrapped it in <Controller />,but I dont know if it is right, I am new to React,code:- [https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-lake-ipegx?file=/index.html] @knoefel

Comment: You have to put the code in a component file (`.jsx` or `.tsx`) instead of a using a `.html` file. Just follow the Sandbox i posted in my previous comment and would  also suggest to go trough the react docs as well.